# Break a loop by pressing a button Tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, tkinter

My program has lots of tasks inside a while loop to do I need to make a button to break the loop
it's an example :

```
from tkinter import *
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

class screen():
    def __init__(self):
        self.no = 1

    def close(self):
        #what should i do?

    def go(self,a,b,c,d):
        self.close = Button(self.window, text=f"{d}close", width=10, height=2, command=self.close)
            self.close.grid(row=4+d,column=1,columnspan=3,padx=5, pady=5)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="webdriver")
        while True:
            driver.get(a)
            sleep(11)
            print("1 done")
            driver.get(b)
            sleep(5)
            print("2 done")
            driver.get(c)
            sleep(5)
            print("3 done")
            print(f"we will go to your {d}th 3 website again")
        driver.close()

    def start(self):
        a = self.Entry1.get()
        b = self.Entry2.get()
        c = self.Entry3.get()
        self.no = self.no + 1
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.go, args=[a,b,c,self.no], daemon=True).start()

    def tkin(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("selenium task")
        self.label1 = Label(self.window, text="enter your 1 website")
        self.Entry1 = Entry(self.window)
        self.label2 = Label(self.window, text="enter your 2 website")
        self.Entry2 = Entry(self.window)
        self.label3 = Label(self.window, text="enter your 3 website")
        self.Entry3 = Entry(self.window)
        self.button = Button(self.window, text="start", width = 10 , height = 2 , command = self.start)
        self.label1.grid(row=1,column=1, columnspan = 3, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.Entry1.grid(row=1,column=2, columnspan = 3, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.label2.grid(row=2,column=1, columnspan = 3, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.Entry2.grid(row=2,column=2, columnspan = 3, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.label3.grid(row=3,column=1, columnspan = 3, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.Entry4.grid(row=3,column=2, columnspan = 3, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.button.grid(row=4,column=1, columnspan = 3, padx=5, pady=5)
```

I need to click on the close button to break this loop at any website (1 or 2 or 3 I don't know when the user will click) or a way to close the selenium which I clicked its close number

Answer (score 0):

You can have the `screen.close()` method set a variable to `True` if the loop needs to be broken. The loop should run only if the variable is `True`. Here is the code, with the added and edited lines marked accordingly:

```
from tkinter import *
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

class screen():
    def __init__(self):
        self.no = 1
        self.break_loop = False ### ADDED LINE

    def close(self):
        self.break_loop = True ### ADDED LINE

    def go(self,a,b,c,d):
        self.close_button = Button(self.window, text=f"{d}close", width=10, height=2, command=self.close) ### EDITED LINE
        self.close_button.grid(row=4+d,column=1,columnspan=3,padx=5, pady=5) ### EDITED LINE
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="webdriver")
        while not self.break_loop: ### EDITED LINE
            driver.get(a)
            sleep(11)
            print("1 done")
            driver.get(b)
            sleep(5)
            print("2 done")
            driver.get(c)
            sleep(5)
            print("3 done")
            print(f"we will go to your {d}th 3 website again")
        self.break_loop = False ### ADDED LINE
        driver.close()

    def start(self):
        a = self.Entry1.get()
        b = self.Entry2.get()
        c = self.Entry3.get()
        self.no = self.no + 1
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.go, args=[a,b,c,self.no], daemon=True).start()

    def tkin(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("selenium task")
        self.label1 = Label(self.window, text="enter your 1 website")
        self.Entry1 = Entry(self.window)
        self.label2 = Label(self.window, text="enter your 2 website")
        self.Entry2 = Entry(self.window)
        self.label3 = Label(self.window, text="enter your 3 website")
        self.Entry3 = Entry(self.window)
        self.button = Button(self.window, text="start", width = 10 , height = 2 , command = self.start)
        self.label1.grid(row=1,column=1, columnspan = 3, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.Entry1.grid(row=1,column=2, columnspan = 3, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.label2.grid(row=2,column=1, columnspan = 3, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.Entry2.grid(row=2,column=2, columnspan = 3, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.label3.grid(row=3,column=1, columnspan = 3, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.Entry4.grid(row=3,column=2, columnspan = 3, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.button.grid(row=4,column=1, columnspan = 3, padx=5, pady=5)
```

I renamed the close button to `close_button`, so that it doesn't overwrite the `close()` method, which had the same name.

When `close_button` is pressed, `self.break_loop` is set to `True`. The loop runs for only as long as `self.break_loop` is `True`. After the loop runs, `self.break_loop` is set back to `False` again so that the `go()` method can be called again.

Comment: Thanks for your help but i need to break the loop at anytime like i typed the 3 website and the program goes to the 2nd website but i don't want the program to go to the 3rd website so when i click stop i need the loop to break this will make the program go to the 3rd website then break the loop

Comment: @HeshamIbrahim: I edited the code in my answer. This should only run the loop while `self.break_loop` is `False`. I tested it.

Comment: don't import everything from a module and also you could use a loop to create the labels and entries

Comment: @Matiiss: Sorry about all that. I copied and pasted the OP's code, and just changed what I needed to change to get the loop-breaker working.

Comment: @HeshamIbrahim:`Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Fatal Python error: could not acquire lock for <_io.BufferedWriter name='<stderr>'> at interpreter shutdown, possibly due to daemon threads
Python runtime state: finalizing (tstate=0x1d25400)
Thread 0x00007f530b58c700 (most recent call first):

Current thread 0x00007f530da4a740 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
Aborted (core dumped)`

Comment: @HeshamIbrahim: Try using `daemon=False`.

Comment: it worked for me when i typed if statement break in every possible line to close @SamMatzko

Comment: @HeshamIbrahim: You mean that there was no "daemon" error with multiple `if` statements, but there was with a `while not self.break_loop:`?

Comment: yes @SamMatzko i wanted an easy way rather than putting if statements break to make little lines in the code